# Exception when I try to run a liferay portlet on my tomcat server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, liferay

This is what I get:

```
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 8099; nested exception is: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind.
```

I have to mention that I use `liferay 7.0 ga3` and `tomcat 8.0.32`, my ide is `eclipse luna`.

I tried to run in command line start rmiregistry some_port, but it didn't do nothing, just popped up a window and did effectively nothing.
Thank you!

Comment: Port already in use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tomcat uses port 8099 for JMX communication (which is crucial for debugging). There is already another process using this port. Here are some possibilities:

- In general, it is more practical just to finish the other process. *A LOT OF TIMES*, the other process is Spotify. Are you using Spotify? If so, just finish it, start Liferay and then reopen Spotify. Annoying but straightforward.
- You started another Tomcat bundle. In this case, you only have to shut it down.
- A previous Liferay execution just crashed and let a rogue Java process listening on the port. In this case, go to the terminal and execute `jps`:

  ```
    $ jps
    28058 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
    1787 Bootstrap
    14207 Jps
  ```

  Kill the process that is labeled `Bootstrap`:

  ```
    $ kill -9 1787
  ```
- Technically, you could change the port on Tomcat. Open the server configuration, click on "Open Launch Configuration." Then, go to the "Arguments" tab and look for `8099`. Basically, follow the GIF below:

  [image: Changing tomcat port]

  However, I do not know all the consequences of it. I used to do it with Tomcat servers without LDS, not sure what problems it could bring with LDS.

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether the shutdown port mentioned in the `server.xml` file under `liferay-dxp-(version)-ga1\tomcat-(version)\conf` folder.

Use the below command to find the ports running in your windows machine:

```
netstat /nao | findstr "80"
```

then change the shutdown port to any available ports, say 8010:

```
<Server port="8010" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

restart the server.

Please try this step if the shutdown port is already in use.